# Git Clone To Server Responds Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, ssh, key

I've tried everything I can think of and I still keep getting this error:

My Steps:

1) Generate local key to ~/.ssh

2) Copy that key to BitBucket SSH keys for my profile.

3) Added that key to my server at ~/.ssh

Is there something else I'm supposed to do? I am just doing a git clone repo(SSH)

Comment: What's the error exactly? Maybe the permission of your ssh private key (chmod 400 on it)?

Comment: Permission denied (publickey) is the only error it gives me

Comment: Do I need to generate a private key? I am an absolute rookie at Git deployment. Don't need you to type me a tut, but maybe move me in the right direction. I generated public keys, and thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, SSH is quite picky about your file and directory permissions. Double check that your `.ssh` directory is `chmod 700`, your key is in a file called `id_rsa` which is `chmod 600`, and that both of these are owned by you.

Secondly, is there an ssh-agent running? `ssh-agent` is a service that can cache your credentials so you don't have to type your password every time you fetch and push, with timeouts and so on if you want them. `ssh` (and therefore `git`) will ask your agent for your key if it's running.

To add a key to the agent, use `ssh-add`. If your key isn't in a file called `id_rsa`, you can also add it by explicit path: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_other_rsa`. Once keys have been added, you should be able to see their fingerprints listed in the output of `ssh-add -l`.

If you aren't running an agent (you'll see "`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`") then it may help to start one with `ssh-agent bash` (then add your keys). If that works, you can use [some shell tricks](https://drupal.star.bnl.gov/STAR/blog-entry/jeromel/2009/feb/06/how-safely-start-ssh-agent-bashrc) to automatically start one for each session on your server.

Comment: Oh man I figured it out. Thanks guys, turns out I copied the wrong key into my .ssh directory on my server.